# Upate hash parameter in Android WebView

Tags: java, android, android-webview, single-page-application

I want to update the url hash parameter of a Webview. It reloads the url, if the base url changes, but not if the hash does.

```
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MyClass {

    private WebView myWebView;

    public void start() {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> {
            this.assistantWebView.loadUrl("https://www.myCoolName.de/index.html");
        }

        MyClass self = this;

        new android.os.Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> {
                         self.myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.myCoolName.de/index.html#myValue");
                    });
                }
            }, 8000);
     }
}
```

After 8 seconds the page flickers shortly, but it did not change anything.

How do I update a page with hashtags?

Comment: this is just a thought, but shouldn't you be inserting ```&#35;``` or ```%A3```?

Comment: Good thought, but unfortunately it doesn't work. `%23` either.

Comment: strange. can we try how this would behave on desktop chromium. if all else fails we could just make changes and update webview address bar component via native for these cases. webview has given me much trouble if i didn't extend it and added the javascriptweb interface

Comment: In desktop chrome it reloads after I entered the address the second time in the address bar. Maybe I should call `loadUrl` again after it finished loading? 
For now I made a workaround by adding an unnecessary get parameter to force rendering (`self.myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.myCoolName.de/index.html?foo=myRandomHashValue#myValue"`), but this could not be the real flow. It would be also great if the page does not reload, just rerender. But I'm not sure if this is possible at all.

Comment: het, if all else fails, just pass url to

Comment: a defined JS function to handle hash navs

Comment: for pages not yours inject the nav function on the after-page-finishes loading function that WebView has

Comment: Thanks for the hint :) The page is not mine, but I could try this.